# How to correct words in panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to correct the miss-spelling in the CSV file containing the sentences.

input_csv:

```
id  text
0   my telephon not working
1   I have mobil in my bag
2   car is expensiv
```

The code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702405/get-the-most-relevant-word-spell-check-from-enchant-suggest-in-python) using enchant corrects the word by providing the suggestion:

I would like to use this spell correction method to correct the words inside the panda dataframe. I have the following code where each sentence is first tokenized and then checks the spelling and suggests the best:

```
import enchant, difflib, nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import pandas as pd

text = "telephon mobil" # This is only a sample
token = word_tokenize(text)

for word in token:
    best_words = []
    best_ratio = 0
    a = set(d.suggest(word))
    for b in a:
        tmp = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, word, b).ratio()
        if tmp > best_ratio:
            best_words = [b]
            best_ratio = tmp
        elif tmp == best_ratio:
            best_words.append(b)
    print('word:[', word, '] -> best suggest:[', best_words[0],']')

word:[ telephon ] -> best suggest:[ telephone ]
word:[ mobil ] -> best suggest:[ mobile ]
```

Now my question is, how I can apply this to my panda dataframe and correct the miss-spelling inside each row, and have the output as following:

output_csv:

```
id  text
0   my telephone not working
1   I have mobile in my bag
2   car is expensive
```

Comment: try turning it into a function and use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to run the function on each cell

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for the comment. Can you please show with a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function and then call it on each row using `apply`:

```
def word_suggest(word):
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    if d.check(word):
        return word
    best_words = []
    best_ratio = 0
    a = set(d.suggest(word))
    for b in a:
        tmp = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, word, b).ratio()
        if tmp > best_ratio:
            best_words = [b]
            best_ratio = tmp
        elif tmp == best_ratio:
            best_words.append(b)
    return best_words[0]

>>> df["text"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(word_suggest(word) for word in word_tokenize(x)))
0    my telephone not working
1     I have mobile in my bag
2            car is expensive
Name: text, dtype: object
```